# Parsing data from pdf and formatting it in csv using GREP/awk/sed

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, grep

I have Ubuntu 18.04, and am using GREP and pdftotext to extract information from pdf files.  I can come close to getting what I want, but as a newbie to this, I’m struggling to refine it.  The ultimate goal is to export this information to excel or SQL table, so the formatting and layout is critical.  I’ve used awk and sed to attempt to go straight to csv, BUT I end up with tabs and white space that isn’t clean – let alone normalized in a useful fashion.  I have 3000+ of these reports.

The reports are multi-page that contain some information that I’d like to parse out and store in a csv file. I can successfully convert the pdf to text, and keep the layout and remove the page breaks.  I can also retrieve the info. pretty well, but I’m having trouble with two things: 
1. Including a separate piece of information at the beginning of the report: Name and Date with the information I’m extracting;
2. Piping the information in a useful csv format.
Here’s what I have after converting the pdf to text:

```
Blah blah blah…
Blah blah blah…,

Date:       July 5/2009

Name:     Jerry Lewis

Blah, blah bla blah…
Blah, blah bla blah…
… and so forth…
Blah, blah bla blah…

Program       Signature       Style

ID      

3267-A0            DJFHJJHJHHL      Compact Flash

SJF98SDAS7
```

The headers are separated by white space/tabs.  "ProgramID" is spread over two lines, as is the signature value

I want:

```
Date,Name,ProgramID,Signature,Style
July 5/2009,Jerry Lewis, 3267-A02, DJFHJJHJHHL SJF98SDAS7, Compact Flash
```

The ultimate goal is to export this information to excel or SQL table, so the formatting and layout is critical.  I’ve used awk and sed to attempt to go straight to csv, BUT I end up with tabs and white space that isn’t clean – let alone normalized in a useful fashion.  I have 3000+ of these reports.  What would be super-awesome is to recursively do them all at once.  I’ve meddled in recursive statements to convert all the pdf’s in the folder to text, and used linux command to move the pdf’s as a whole to another “processed” directory but that’s about it.

Like I said, I’m a bit of a newbie, so I’m not even sure if this even possible?  - Thanks

Comment: Save the text into some file. Now : grep the file for `'^Date:'` and remove `Date:` + spaces, ie. `sed 's/^Date:[ ]*//`. Save the result - you have Date. Reapeat for Name. Then do `grep -x -A4 'ID'` - grep for the exact line with `ID` and get 4 lines after it. Then get the second line with ex. `sed -n '2p'` - then extract first string `awk '{print $1}'` - you have ProgramID. Extract second string - you have part of signature. Extract everything after third string, ie. with `tr -s ' ' | cut -s' ' -f3-` - you have style. Extract the rest of signature as the 4th line from the `grep -A3`.

Comment: grep sed grep sed awk tr cut grep , not very efficient. I think you can use only one awk ...

Comment: Since `awk` and `sed` are Turing complete, then if a task is computable either tool can do it alone.   That said, this kind of job in `sed` is pure masochism...

Comment: You mean iterative, not recursive, right? You want to iterate over 3,000+ files?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately most of what the script needs to do (i.e. avoid false matches) depends on the text that you just provided "blah"s for and whatever you meant by "white spaces/tabs" when you wrote `The headers are separated by white space/tabs` but **maybe** this will point you in the right direction:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    numTags = split("Date Name Program Signature Style",tagNr2name)
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tagName = tagNr2name[tagNr]
        tagName2nr[tagName] = tagNr
        tagNameColon2nr[tagName":"] = tagNr
    }
    FS = "[[:space:]]{2,}"
    OFS = ","
}

{ gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"") }

$1 in tagNameColon2nr {
    tagNr = tagNameColon2nr[$1]
    val = $0
    sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]+/,"",val)
    tagNr2val[tagNr] = val
}

$1 in tagName2nr {
    lineNr = 1
}

lineNr {
    if ( lineNr == 1 ) {
        for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
            fldNr2tagNr[fldNr] = tagName2nr[$fldNr]
        }
    }
    else if ( lineNr == 5 ) {
        for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
            tagNr = fldNr2tagNr[fldNr]
            tagNr2val[tagNr] = $fldNr
        }
    }

    if ( lineNr == 7 ) {
        tagNr = tagName2nr["Signature"]
        tagNr2val[tagNr] = tagNr2val[tagNr] " " $1

        if ( !(printedHdr++) ) {
            for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
                printf "%s%s", tagNr2name[tagNr], (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
        for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", tagNr2val[tagNr], (tagNr<numTags ? OFS : ORS)
        }
        delete tagNr2val
        lineNr = 0
    }
    else {
        lineNr++
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Date,Name,Program,Signature,Style
July 5/2009,Jerry Lewis,3267-A0,DJFHJJHJHHL SJF98SDAS7,Compact Flash
```

You can tweak "Program" to "ProgramID" when printing the header line if it actually matters.